# Accessing NSImageView giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I've got a strange problem here.

I have a class that I'll call `MainView`.  In `MainView` I have one `NSImageView`, which I'll call `imageView`.  I've hooked this up to an image view through Interface Builder.  I've also initialized an instance of `MainView` in Interface Builder, and have connected an outlet to that instance to another class with an ivar name of `mainView`.  So then, I access the image view like this:

```
[mainView imageView]
```

So then, for a test I `NSLog`'d the `imageView` and it returned the address of the objet.  So far so good.

Here's the problem: now I'm trying to get the origin of that `imageView` by doing this:

```
NSPoint point = [[mainView imageView] frame].origin;
```

This should work, right?  I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (also got a SIGABRT once) warning here with the error in console of: `-[NSImage frame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001d5fd0`

The strange part is that this always used work just fine, but I changed some ivar names and it seemed to mess up the whole thing.  I almost know for certain it's not a hookup issue with IB because I get a memory address when I log the object.  Any ideas?

Comment: See this link: http://loufranco.com/blog/files/Understanding-EXC_BAD_ACCESS.html

Comment: Now it's SIGABRT, not EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  I believe Bavarious is on the right track.  I'm trying to set a NSImage instead of a NSImageView.

Comment: Hooray, thanks!  Please post your comment as an answer.  I ended up doing this stupidly: `mainView.imageView = [NSImage imageNamed:@"blah"];`, basically setting the NSImageView to a NSImage.  I switched to the `setImage:` method instead, and all's good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message

> -[NSImage frame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001d5fd0

means that `imageView` is pointing to an `NSImage` object instead of an `NSImageView` object. It looks like somewhere in your code you’re reassigning the `imageView` outlet, making it point to an `NSImage` instance.

Comment: I'll accept it as soon as it's available.  Nice catch, and thank you.